# Hashes as arguments and default argument values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am perusing some of the Rails internals, particularly the has_many method. It shows the following examples:

```
  # Option examples:
  #   has_many :comments, -> { order "posted_on" }
  #   has_many :comments, -> { includes :author }
  #   has_many :people, -> { where(deleted: false).order("name") }, class_name: "Person"
  #   has_many :tracks, -> { order "position" }, dependent: :destroy
  #   has_many :comments, dependent: :nullify
  #   has_many :tags, as: :taggable
  #   has_many :reports, -> { readonly }
  #   has_many :subscribers, through: :subscriptions, source: :user
  def has_many(name, scope = nil, options = {}, &extension)
    reflection = Builder::HasMany.build(self, name, scope, options, &extension)
    Reflection.add_reflection self, name, reflection
  end
```

Look at this one in particular:

```
has_many :subscribers, through: :subscriptions, source: :user
```

The second argument is a hash. And I noticed it gets assigned to the options local variable. But why didn't it get assigned to the scope variable, since the scope variable is the second argument in the argument list? Why was the scope variable skipped during assignment? I no that it sets a default value of nil, if no second argument is passed in, but in fact a second argument was passed in.

Comment: That's not the [signature of `has_many` in Rails 5.2](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many). What version of Rails are you looking at?

Comment: @Schwern this is ActiveRecord 4.2.7 from Rails 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the definition of `has_many` changed between Rails 4 and Rails 5. Let's start with Rails 4.

## Rails 4

You are correct that something fishy is going on here. Rails is cheating. I'm going to guess for backwards compatibilty with older versions of Ruby which didn't have as rich an argument syntax as now.

`name`, `scope`, and `options` are all positional arguments. We can define `has_many` to see what's going on.

```
def has_many(name, scope = nil, options = {}, &extension)
  puts "name: #{name}"
  puts "scope: #{scope}"
  puts "options: #{options}"
  puts "extension: #{extension}"
end
```

If we run `has_many :subscribers, through: :subscriptions, source: :user`...

```
name: subscribers
scope: {:through=>:subscriptions, :source=>:user}
options: {}
extension:
```

Well that's not right. [Let's look at its source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.2.10/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations.rb#L1258)...

```
def has_many(name, scope = nil, options = {}, &extension)
  reflection = Builder::HasMany.build(self, name, scope, options, &extension)
  Reflection.add_reflection self, name, reflection
end
```

The arguments are passed through to [`Builder::HasMany.build`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.2.10/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/builder/association.rb#L28) which calls `create_builder model, name, scope, options, &block`. That calls `new(model, name, scope, options, &block)` to create a new instance. [In its initializer](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.2.10/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/builder/association.rb#L50) we find this...

```
def initialize(model, name, scope, options)
  # TODO: Move this to create_builder as soon we drop support to activerecord-deprecated_finders.
  if scope.is_a?(Hash)
    options = scope
    scope   = nil
  end
  ...
```

So it's just cheating. If `scope` is a hash it switches it to `options`. This is a pretty nasty hack, seeing as how the wrong arguments go through several layers of method calls before they're fixed.

## Rails 5

Rails 5 changed the signature of `has_many`.

```
def has_many(name, scope = nil, **options, &extension)
  puts "name: #{name}"
  puts "scope: #{scope}"
  puts "options: #{options}"
  puts "extension: #{extension}"
end

has_many :subscribers, through: :subscriptions, source: :user
```

And now it works as it's supposed to.

```
name: subscribers
scope: 
options: {:through=>:subscriptions, :source=>:user}
extension:
```

[`**` converts keyword arguments to a hash](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Hash+to+Keyword+Arguments+Conversion) and this makes it work.

- `name` is a required [positional argument](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Positional+Arguments).
- `scope = nil` is a [positional argument that has a default](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Default+Positional+Arguments), so it's optional.
- `**options` is a [keyword argument](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Keyword+Arguments) that will [convert the keywords into a hash](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Hash+to+Keyword+Arguments+Conversion).
- `&extension` is a [block argument](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Block+Argument).

When you call `has_many :subscribers, through: :subscriptions, source: :user` this is what happens.

1. Ruby needs the first positional `name` so it takes `:subscribers`.
2. Ruby needs the second positional `scope`, but it's run out of positional, the rest of the arguments are keywords, so it uses the default `nil`.
3. Ruby slurps up the keywords and puts them in the `options` hash.
4. `extension` is a block argument and it's fine if those are left off.

You can read more about how argument processing happens in Ruby in the [Calling Methods document](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Keyword+Arguments).

Comment: AFAIK Rails4 still supported Ruby versions that didn't have keyword arguments. I'm not certain about that but it is important to keep in mind that there are layers of history behind this stuff.

Answer (score 1):

The hash was assigned to the `scope` parameter, since it was passed in as the second parameter, thus leaving `options` to get its default value of `{}`. But, ActiveRecord swaps the parameters around if you pass a hash as the second value. This is handled in [`Builder::Association`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-2-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/builder/association.rb) (which is used because `Builder::HasMany` inherits from `Builder:: CollectionAssociation`  which in turn inherits from `Builder::Association`). The [`build`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-2-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/builder/association.rb#L28) class method calls [`create_builder`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-2-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/builder/association.rb#L44) which then passes the arguments onto [`initialize`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-2-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/builder/association.rb#L50) which checks

```
if scope.is_a?(Hash)
  options = scope
  scope   = nil
end
```

So no built-in ruby behind-the-scenes magic, `ActiveRecord` just chose to do a check to see if you passed a `Hash` as the second parameter and 'fix' it for you, instead of forcing you to pass `nil`.

---

[`CollectionAssociation`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-2-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/builder/collection_association.rb#L17) does override the `initialize` method, but you can see they do call super at the start of the method, making sure that `Association#initialize` gets called first and this param swapping happens.

Comment: A lot of view helpers (such as `link_to`, `tag.span`, ...) do similar argument list interpreting so that they can pretend to have different signatures when you use them with a block. This is a fairly common pattern in Rails with all its DWIM attitude.